# Is it possible to register powershell scheduled job from another scheduled job?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, windows-scripting

I have a set of PS1 scripts and the goal is to automate the registration of the PowerShell jobs.

```
#Manager.ps1
function registerJobs {
    & "C:\scripts\Worker1.ps1"
    & "C:\scripts\Worker2.ps1"
}
```

```
#Worker1.ps1
$trig = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "5:00 AM"
Register-ScheduledJob -Name doSomething -FilePath C:\scripts\doSomething.ps1 -Trigger $trig
```

```
#Worker2.ps1
$trig = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "6:00 AM"
Register-ScheduledJob -Name doSomethingElse -FilePath C:\scripts\doSomethingElse.ps1 -Trigger $trig
```

If run Manager.ps1 from Powershell console
Results: Both doSomething and doSomethingElse appears in Scheduled Tasks as expected

If Manager.ps1 is scheduled like a job.

```
$trig = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "0:00 AM"
Register-ScheduledJob -Name Manager -FilePath C:\scripts\Manager.ps1 -Trigger $trig
```

Results:

1. Manager.ps1 is registered in Scheduled Tasks
2. But when you run it "Manager" scheduled job is always in a state "The task is currently running" and doSomething and doSomethingEkse jobs never appear in Scheduled Tasks

The idea is to have a manager that will look for scripts in some folder and if a new script appears then it will be automatically executed and job is registered.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I overthought the problem. All I had to do was move Worker1 and Worker2 into Manager and then register it as a scheduled job.